# spring webflow and parameter passing

Tags: spring-webflow

I  have this application based on  SWF2.0.
Its a questionaire(like GRE questionaire) where based on user's selection next question is decided.

Also i have next/previous and save & exit buttons on each page.
So i have flow definitions and tiles and JSP.I have one base JSP page -called template.jsp
which stores header(Question No 'num') and buttons (back/next/save & exist) as they appear on every page.
So each JSP page inherits template.jsp.

Now i want this Question No 'NUM' to be dynamically calculated with each nextt and prev click .
How do i accomplish that.
I cannt hard code and pass ques no from flow file.

Answer (score 0):

Having session variable indicating number of question and increase/decrease its value on next/previous buttons (during validation) might help you.